# Optimize integration volume under integral constraint

Tags: optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem and  I am almost sure there exist some theorem which already does it:
Let there be two probability density functions: $f_1(x_1,x_2...x_d),f_2(x_1,x_2...x_d)$

The d dimension space V can be is divided into 2, such that:
$ V_1\cup V_2 = V $

The problem at hand is:
Find the $V_1,V_2$ that maximizes:$\int_{V_1}f_1(x_1,x_2..x_d)$

under the constraint:
$\int_{V_1}f_2(x_1,x_2..x_d)=C    $